# Removing Duplicates in a Google Sheets Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have spreadsheet with some data in it:

```
Staff No. - First Name - Last Name - Age
12345     - John       - Doe       - 29
12345     - John       - Doe       - 30
12456     - Jane       - Doe       - 29
12345     - John       - Doe       - 29
```

I have found some code that allows me to remove duplicate rows.
Using the above "Spreadsheet Data" as an example, I would be able to remove the 4th entry no problem. Unfortunately this is not what the user is looking for.

I need to adapt the following code to search the values in the first column (and not the entire row), if a match is found, add the row to the temporary array.

In other words, using the above "Spreadsheet Data" as an example I would need to have only the first record for John Doe, age 29 returned to the array. The other 2 entries for John Doe would need to be discarded. (While still keeping the entry for Jane Doe.)

**The Code:**

```
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Duplicate Removal Tool')
        .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Commands').addItem('Remove Duplicates', 'removeDuplicates')).addToUi();
}

function removeDuplicates() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive() // Gets the Spreadsheet where the code is located in.
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); // Gets the Sheet the user is currently focused on.
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // Gets the values of the above sheet.
    var newData = new Array(); // Creates a temporary blank array.

    for (i in data) {

        var row = data[i] // Row Variable equals element of array for current iteration of loop.
        var duplicate = false; // Duplicate variable set to default on each iteration of outer loop.

        for (j in newData) {

            if (row.join() == newData[j].join()) { //Converts elements of the arrays to string and compare values.
                duplicate = true;
            }
        }
        if (!duplicate) {
            newData.push(row); // If rows do not match add current element in row array to newData array.
        }
    }


    sheet.clearContents(); // Clear the contents of the sheet
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length) 
        .setValues(newData); // Write values of newData array to sheet.
}
```

**Attempt Number 2:**
    Here is my second attempt. Works well for the most part. Throws a rows are out of bound error. No problem, that is easy to fix. Problem with this version is it works well enough on 50-100 records. Take it up to 500+ records and execution time goes through the roof:

```
function removeDuplicates() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var newData = []

  var i, j, outerLoopRow, innerLoopRow, lastRow;

  lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  for (i=1; i < lastRow; i++) {
    outerLoopRow = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 1).getValue();

    if (i == lastRow) break


    for (j= i +1; j < lastRow+1; j++) {
      innerLoopRow = sheet.getRange(j,1,1,1).getValue()
      if (outerLoopRow == innerLoopRow){
        ss.deleteRow(j)
      }

   } // End of Inner Loop
  } // End of OuterLoop

} //End of Function
```

Comment: Sounds easy enough, what errors are you getting in your changes that you haven't figured out?

Comment: Got something I am working on at the moment. Will post an update once i have a working POC.

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks for the interest. The 2nd version I wrote ended up hitting the 5 minute execution time when using as little as 500+ records. The version below works well enough. (Tested with 3000+ records and comes in at 200-400 seconds execution time.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code I used to get the desired result.
Explanation on how it all works is in the comments.
If anyone looking at this needs some help, feel free to PM me and I will do my best to help out where I can.

```
//Add Menu to current Sheet
function onOpen(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Duplicate Removal Tool')
    .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Commands').addItem('Remove Duplicates', 'removeDuplicates')).addToUi();
}

function removeDuplicates() {
  // Insert Spreadsheet ID below
  // Insert name of Sheet in spreadsheet below
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET ID HERE");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SHEET NAME HERE");

  //Create Variables
  var array1, array2, array3, lastRow, i, j, k, rowToDelete, reverseArray;

  lastRow = sheet.getLastRow(); // Get last row in sheet with data
  array1 = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow, 1).getValues(); // Get all values in column A
  array2 = array1 // Copy array1 (All values in A)
  array3 = [] // Create a blank array

  // Outer Loop - Perform Inner Loop for each value in array 1
  // Inner loop, compare first value against all other values in descending order.
  // If match is found, check if value already exists in array 3
  // If value does not exist, push the row number to array 3
  for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < array2.length; j++) {
      if (array1[i].join() == array2[j].join()) {
        if(array3.indexOf(j + 2) == -1)
          array3.push(j + 2)
      }
    } // End of Inner Loop
  } // End of Outer Loop

  //Sort Array 3 in numerical order.
  // Reverse array so highest value is first and lowest value is last
  // For each value in array 3, delete the row with corresponding number in array 3
  reverseArray = array3.sort(function (a, b) {  return a - b;  }).reverse()
  for (k = 0; k < array3.length; k++) {
    rowToDelete = reverseArray[k];
    ss.deleteRow(rowToDelete);
  }
}// End of Function
```

Comment: Note that you can improve this still, by doing things like calling `array1[i].join()` once per outer iteration, `.splice`ing or skipping found duplicates from  `array1` (take note that you did not actually copy array1 into array2 if you opt for splice...), caching `.length` calculations (if you are not modifying the arrays in the loops), etc.

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks Tehhowch, started adding in your recommendations. (Seems so obvious once pointed out.) Going to try test this the weekend, otherwise only Monday. Will post updated code and will try to note the difference between execution time. Hope you have a lekka weekend!

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks for all the recommendations, managed to notice a solid performance increase with your suggestions.

Comment: Could you please provide some instructions on how to set this up?

Comment: You need to set your spreadsheet ID, spreadsheet Name and the range. (Range is set at array1.)   This script can be bound to a spreadsheet (for menus) or it can be standalone (no menus).

Comment: Thanks. I got an error saying - "Those rows are out of bounds. (line 41, file "RemoveDupe3")

Comment: Hmmm... Sounds like row you are trying to delete is out of bounds. /s - Do a little research, try understand what the code is doing. Don't have the time to help troubleshoot every issue.